# Problems with installation of Android Studio on Windows 10

Tags: java, android, eclipse, git, android-studio

Unable to install Android Studio on Windows 10 64-bit Operating System
Java 1.8.0_121
Android Studio 2.2.3 
Gradle 2.14.1

> java.io.IOException: Cannot download
>   'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r44.zip':
>   Read timed out , response: 200 OK Warning: An error occurred while
>   preparing SDK package Android Support Repository: Cannot download
>   'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r44.zip':
>   Read timed out , response: 200 OK. java.io.IOException: Cannot
>   download
>   'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/google_m2repository_gms_v9_rc41_wear_2_0_rc6.zip':
>   Read timed out , response: 200 OK Warning: An error occurred while
>   preparing SDK package Google Repository: Cannot download
>   'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/google_m2repository_gms_v9_rc41_wear_2_0_rc6.zip':
>   Read timed out , response: 200 OK.

What is possibly going wrong with this installation?'

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue? I'm stuck with this issue both on Windows and Linux. Guess this is some network issue?

Comment: I work behind a proxy network. When I used a network without proxy it worked just fine.

Answer (score 2):

I had this similar issue, solution below worked for me. 
The solution for this is:

1) Run Android Studio as Administrator.

2) Re run the update.

It will definitely work.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and what I did, was download the file that came with the error, https://dl.google.com/android/repository/google_m2repository_gms_v11_3_rc05_wear_2_0_5.zip 
that file I copied into the folder C: \ Users \ USER \ AppData \ Local \ Android \ Sdk \ extras. 
Finally I went back to running Android Developer as Administrator, and it worked!.